# Sql jobs execution in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent-job

I want to find out if my db server is executing more than one sql jobs (long running/complex) at a time, will this give you timeouts in other queries?

jobs may belong to different databases, running on different drives.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can identify long running jobs ([one](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3500276/Identifying-Long-Running-SQL-Server-Agent-Jobs.htm) and [two](http://blog.stevienova.com/2009/11/13/sql-server-agent-query-to-find-long-running-jobs/))

SQL Server agent though is just another client that uses resources, locks etc like your web site or whatever. It could block, it may not block: like your web site.